# Client side iCalendar Event Creator

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, icalendar

I need to add some functionality to a web application that allows a user to create an event which will be added to a calendar. I would like to give the user as much flexibility as possible when created events (single events, recurring events, etc) ... bascially as much of the flexibility that iCalendar allows for its Events as possible.

I have started to look into building this myself, but I would rather not reinvent the wheel if something exists (and custimize it accordingly). Anyone have any ideas of any javascript/jquery library that allows you to create events which can be imported into an iCalendar? Bascially the client functionality I need is something similar to the google calendars 'create event' page.

Comment: What I am looking for is a front end that allows someone to create an event (start, end, recurring options, etc) and will output a corresponding iCalendar object that could be added to an iCalenday ... similar to the google calender gui: http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/686a3d8b7e.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the link.

I have decided to roll my own front end since there doesnt seem to be something suitable already created.

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Can you make your code open source? I'm in need of the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery iCalendar](http://keith-wood.name/icalendar.html)

Comment: Sorry, i might be missing it, but i can't see any part of the plugin that display's a gui that lets a end user input the event data (specifically recurring event data). Sorry if i am missing it

Answer (score 0):

Peter - recurring events are incredibly complicated.
I found that it took way longer than I had planned to achieve what you are looking for.
I have done it as a wordpress plugin (with the idea to offer standalone later.  You an play with it here - wait a day s I have an update to apply to test site icalevents.anmari.com/test

You may find some of the notes on the main site helpful too icalevents.anmari.com (links to ical RFC 5545  resources at bottom right)

Whoops - sorry just saw you wanted client side - mine is php based with html/js front end.